# RxJava 2.x - An Observable getting flatMap triggered by a PublishSubject and merged with other Observables does not get subscribed/executed

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a pagination solution using a `PublishSubject` that looks like this:

```
    private val pages: PublishSubject<Int> = PublishSubject.create()
    val observable: Observable<List<Data> = pages.hide()
        .filter { !inFlight }
        .doOnNext { inFlight = true }
        .flatMap{
            getPage(it) // Returns an Observable
        }
        .doOnNext(::onNextPage) // inFlight gets reset here
```

This `Observable` is merged and scanned with other `Observable`´s like this:

```
    fun stateObservable(): Observable<SavedState> {
        return Observable.merge(listOf(firstPage(),
            nextPage(),// The observable listed above
            refresh()))
            .scan(MyState.initialState(), StateReducer::reduce)
    }
```

Basically I have a unidirectional setup where every observable updates `MyState` with its relevant changes with the help of the accumulator function `reduce`.

In the `ViewModel` this is consumed in a straight forward way:

```
        interactor.stateObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeBy(onNext = ::render, onError = Timber::e)
            .addTo(subscriptions)
```

This setup works well for `firstPage` as well as `refresh` (Also triggered with the help of `PublishSubject`) but for some reason the paging solution get's as for as returning the `getPage` `Observable` in the `flatMap` but then this page `Observable` never gets triggered/subscribed to and the `doOnNext` after the `flatMap` obviously doesn't get called either. It seems like it basically doesn't wanna subscribe to it and I simply don't know why.

The `getPage` function looks like this:

```
    private fun getPage(page: Long): Observable<PartialState<SavedState>> {
        return repo.getPage(page).firstOrError().toObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map<PartialState<MyState>> { NextPageLoaded(it) }
            .onErrorReturn { NextPageError(it) }
            .startWith { NextPageLoading() }
    }
```

The `getPage` in the repo is converting an RxJava 1 `Observable` to an RxJava2 `Observable` with the help of `RxJavaInterop` in the following way:

```
    public io.reactivex.Observable<List<Data>> getPage(long page) {
        Observable<List<Data>> observable = getPage(page)
                .map(dataList -> {
                    if(dataList == null){
                        dataList = new ArrayList<>();
                    }
                    return dataList;
                });

        return RxJavaInterop.toV2Observable(observable);
    }
```

Im not getting any errors so you can rule that out.

I already have this very same setup with RxJava 1 where it is working very well and now when I'm migrating to 2.x I was expecting the same solution to work but I'm completely stuck on this pagination issue and in all other scenarios the setup is working as expected.

To be able to test the issue I have uploaded a sample project on [GitHub](https://github.com/tobbelindberg/PaginationIssue) demonstrating the issue.

Any RxJava expert out there that have a clue on what it could be? :)

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear if you drive `pages: PublishSubject` from the same thread, if not, apply `toSerialized()`. Also `inFlight` is set but perhaps not cleared or accessed from multiple threads and may not become visible. I assume this is from some project you can't share so could you create a project demonstrating this problem?

Comment: Hello @akarnokd . Glad to see that such a pro caught my attention :) I have tested with `toSerialized() ` and noticed no difference. `inFlight` get's reset just after the `flatMap` in the `.doOnNext(::onNextPage)`.

As requested I have uploaded a sample project to GitHub (https://github.com/tobbelindberg/PaginationIssue) demonstrating the issue.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Your `inFlight` is a regular `boolean`, but if it is not `volatile` then it will most likely not work. You can also use `AtomicBoolean` instead.

Comment: I don't think `inFlight` is the issue here or at least not the main issue. The problem is that the observable never get's subscribed to. I however tried to making it an `AtomicBoolean` anyway just in case and the issue is still there unfortunately :/

Comment: Where do you subscribe to the pager flow? I can't find any use of `subscribe(`.

Comment: The `PaginationIssueInteractor` merges all observables including `pager.observable` in the `stateObservable()` function and this `stateObservable()` is called by by the `PaginationIssueViewModel` where the kotlin subscribe `subscribeBy` is called.

Comment: Not sure what I should see. I see 8 numbers and can scroll up to 10, but after that, `OnLoadMoreListener` in `paginationScrollListener` doesn't even get called. I don't know how these view components operate.

Comment: @akarnokd That sounds strange, are you sure you waited for the debugger to get attached? On my end `onLoadMoreListener` does get called when you scroll to the bottom of the list.

Comment: @akarnokd And that calls `PaginationIssueViewModel `s `onLoadMore()` that calls the `PaginationIssueInteractor `s `onNextPage()` that triggers the `Pager`s `PublishSubject` that `flatMap` triggers to get the  `nextPageObservable` and this is where my issue is. This `nextPageObservable`  doesn't get subscribed too.  It only does it if I actually put a subscribe inside the `flatMap` but I was expecting my `PaginationIssueInteractor `s `stateObservable()` that PaginationIssueViewModel` subscribes too to pick up that next page observable.

Comment: Btw, I pushed one more commit to the example project where I changed it to atomic boolean mentioned by @EpicPandaForce and I also lowered the "Working hard" from 4 seconds to 1.5s in the repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an issue: an over-eager usage of the `{}` creating a lambda for `startWith` which does nothing (and thus never switches to the page chain) in `nextPageObservable`.

```
.startWith { NextPageLoading() }
```

Instead:

```
.startWith ( NextPageLoading() )
```

With this change, however, your code procuces an IAE due to null value somewhere else:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter page
    at com.paginationissue.ui.list.PaginationIssueInteractor$1.invoke(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.paginationissue.ui.list.PaginationIssueInteractor$1.invoke(PaginationIssueInteractor.kt:15)
    at com.paginationissue.paging.PageNumberTokenStrategy.generateNextPageToken(PageNumberTokenStrategy.kt:21)
    at com.paginationissue.paging.PageNumberTokenStrategy.generateNextPageToken(PageNumberTokenStrategy.kt:12)
    at com.paginationissue.paging.Pager.onNextPage(Pager.kt:92)
```

Comment: Solved that issue now also and pushed a fully working pagination solution. Thanks again for all the help :)